# middleware.ts TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading modules)

Tags: typescript, next.js, node-sqlite3, next.js14

I'm messing around with user authentication for a small personal project.

I'm trying to protect certain routes using middleware in Next.js

middleware.ts:

```
import { Authentication } from '@/helpers/auth';

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";


// Invoked on each request to the server
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    
    const auth = Authentication.getInstance();

    // If no session cookie exists
    if (!request.cookies.has(LOGINCOOKIENAME)) return NextResponse.redirect( new URL('/login', request.url));

    // Check Authentication
    
    const cookie = Number(request.cookies.get(LOGINCOOKIENAME)?.value);
    
    if (auth.isAuthenticated(cookie)) return NextResponse.redirect( new URL('/login', request.url));

    return;
}

// Include only selected routes
export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/client',
        '/translator',
        '/manager'
    ]
};
```

I've narrowed down the error to the line `const auth = Authentication.getInstance();`.

auth.ts:

```
import { Database } from "./SQL";

type ID = Number | undefined;

export enum AuthLevel {
    manager,
    translator,
    client
};

export enum LoginCodes {
    success,
    failure,
    username_or_password_incorrect
}

export interface Session {
    userID: ID;
    level: AuthLevel;
}

export class Authentication {
    private sessions: Session[];
    private static instance: Authentication;

    constructor() {
        this.sessions = new Array<Session>();
    }

    public static getInstance(): Authentication {
        if (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = new Authentication();
        }

        return this.instance;
    }

    public isAuthenticated(userID: ID): boolean {
        // Check if session exists already
        for (let session of this.sessions) {
            if (session.userID === userID) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    // Inputs will already be validated
    public async login(username: string, password: string) {
        const database: Database = Database.getInstance();
        
        const results = await database.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?', [username, password]);

        // No matching users
        if (results.length === 0) {
            return {
                success: false,
                message: LoginCodes.username_or_password_incorrect,
            }
        }

        return {
            success: true,
            LoginCode: LoginCodes.success,
            session: {
                userID: 0,
                AuthLevel: AuthLevel.manager
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Following down the rabbit hole, the line `const database: Database = Database.getInstance();` in `Authentication::login()` is causing problems.

SQL.ts (file containing the `Database` class):

```
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";
import fs from 'fs';

const DBPATH: string = './database.db'


export class Database {
    private DB: sqlite3.Database;
    private static instance: Database;

    constructor() {
        this.DB = this.openConnection(DBPATH);
    }

    private openConnection(pathToDatabase: string): sqlite3.Database {
        return new sqlite3.Database(pathToDatabase, sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
            if (err?.message == "SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file") {
                // Create new file
                const newFile = fs.createWriteStream(pathToDatabase);
                newFile.end();

                return this.openConnection(pathToDatabase);
            }

            if (err) return console.error(err.message);
        });
    }

    public static getInstance(): Database {
        if(!this.instance) {
            this.instance = new Database();
        }

        return Database.instance;
    }

    public async statement(sql: string, params?: any) {
        this.DB.run(sql, params, (err) => {
            console.error(err?.message);
        });
    }

    public async query(sql: string, params?: any): Promise<Array<any>> {
        const that = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            that.DB.all(sql, params, (err,rows) => {
               if(err){ return reject(err); }
               resolve(rows);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modules')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js (17)
modules
node_modules\bindings\bindings.js (29:23)
(middleware)/./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
file:///C:/Users/Mazec/Documents/GitHub/translation-suite-nextjs/.next/server/src/middleware.js (95:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/Mazec/Documents/GitHub/translation-suite-nextjs/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///C:/Users/Mazec/Documents/GitHub/translation-suite-nextjs/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (268:21)
require
node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js (1:17)
(middleware)/./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js
file:///C:/Users/Mazec/Documents/GitHub/translation-suite-nextjs/.next/server/src/middleware.js (623:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/Mazec/Documents/GitHub/translation-suite-nextjs/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///C:/Users/Mazec/Documents/GitHub/translation-suite-nextjs/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (268:21)
require
node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js (2:16)
(middleware)/./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
file:///C:/Users/Mazec/Documents/GitHub/translation-suite-nextjs/.next/server/src/middleware.js (634:1)
```

Removing the line `const database: Database = Database.getInstance();` causes the middleware to redirect back to `/login` as expected.

I've done some Googling but cannot for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong. Any nudge in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.